# Powershell remote session is broken when using custom cmdlet and 3rd-party software is present

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, winrm

We have a custom PS cmdlet that works locally, but in a remote session it seems to corrupt the session and I must exit the session. This problem does not occur unless a specific 3rd-party software package is installed on the remote computer; (that package is required and not in my control). I'm stuck and asking for your insight.

Originally, I was executing this in the context of C# and Runspace (.Net framework 4.5.2).  This was reporting "The WSMan provider host process did not return a proper response."  As that message is less-than-helpful, I then simplified by using an interactive shell and enter-pssession, eliminating .Net from the equation.

**Example#1**, remote-desktop to the remote computer, the cmdlt (Get-ToolVersion) works fine

```
Magnus@192.168.19.7# Get-ToolVersion VISA 
Tool    Version
VISA  15.0.0.49
```

**Example#2**, also works fine in a remote session ... IFF 3rd-party VISA is Not installed

```
PS C:\Users\Tom> enter-pssession 192.168.1.6 -credential Tom
[192.168.19.6]: PS C:\Users\Tom\Documents> cd C:\Austin\Installers\PowerShellScripts\
[192.168.19.6]: PS C:\Austin\Installers\PowerShellScripts> Import-Module D:\Austin\Bin\TerToolUtilities.dll -Function Get-ToolVersion
[192.168.19.6]: PS C:\Austin\Installers\PowerShellScripts> Get-ToolVersion QUD
Tool Version
QUD  1.00.52
```

**Example#3** in a remote session, I get an error "The WSMan provider host process did not return a proper response."

```
PS C:\Users\Tom> enter-pssession 192.168.1.7 -credential Tom
[192.168.19.7]: PS C:\Users\Tom\Documents> cd C:\Austin\Installers\PowerShellScripts\
[192.168.19.7]: PS C:\Austin\Installers\PowerShellScripts> Import-Module D:\Austin\Bin\TerToolUtilities.dll -Function Get-ToolVersion
[192.168.19.7]: PS C:\Austin\Installers\PowerShellScripts> Get-ToolVersion VISA
Processing data from remote server 192.168.1.7 failed with the following error message: The WSMan provider host process did not return a proper response.  A provider in the host process may have behaved improperly. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
PS C:\Users\Tom> exit-pssession
```

**Example#4** in a remote session, using the cmdlet to query a different tool (not VISA), it works once and the session is "either closed or broken"

```
PS C:\Users\Tom> enter-pssession 192.168.1.7 -credential Tom
[192.168.19.7]: PS C:\Users\Tom\Documents> cd C:\Austin\Installers\PowerShellScripts\
[192.168.19.7]: PS C:\Austin\Installers\PowerShellScripts> Import-Module D:\Austin\Bin\ToolUtilities.dll -Function Get-ToolVersion
[192.168.19.7]: PS C:\Austin\Installers\PowerShellScripts> Get-ToolVersion QUD
Tool Version
QUD  1.00.52

[192.168.19.7]: PS C:\Austin\Installers\PowerShellScripts> Get-ToolVersion QUD
Command 'Get-ToolVersion QUD' was not run as the session in which it was intended to run was either closed or broken
PS C:\Users\Tom>
```

**The custom cmdlet**
Trying find the problem, I gutted the cmdlet but that did not resolve the error

```
using System;
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "ToolVersion")]
[OutputType(typeof(ToolVersion))]
public class GetToolVersionCmdlet : Cmdlet
{
    private class ToolVersion
    {
        public string Tool { get; set; }
        public string Version { get; set; }
    }

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        try
        {
            string version = null;

            //   <DELETED>

            WriteObject(new ToolVersion { Tool = ToolName, Version = version });    
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteObject(new ToolVersion { Tool = ToolName, Version = "" });
        }
    }
```

**The environment**
PS version and WinRM configuration are the same on the local and remote computers.
The OS is different; local is Windows 10 and remote is Windows Server 2019.
While countless reports of "The WSMan provider host process did not return a proper response" have been attributed to memory config, I find no evidence that is so.

```
Magnus@192.168.19.7# $psversiontable
Name                           Value
PSVersion                      5.1.14393.0
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.14393.0
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1


Magnus@192.168.19.7# winrm get winrm/config/winrs
Winrs
    AllowRemoteShellAccess = true
    IdleTimeout = 7200000
    MaxConcurrentUsers = 2147483647
    MaxShellRunTime = 2147483647
    MaxProcessesPerShell = 2147483647
    MaxMemoryPerShellMB = 2147483647
    MaxShellsPerUser = 2147483647
```

Comment: Check the permissions on your account when you're remoted in, vs when you're not and see what you're missing. It could be that use simply need to use `enter-pssession 192.168.1.7 -credential Tom -EnableNetworkAccess` instead.

Comment: Is WinRM enabled?

Comment: Surprisingly, I have now seen an instance where the 3rd-party software was installed but there is no error.  So, I cannot see what is the thing that is causing the error.

Comparing two computers:  error vs no error.  ("The WSMan provider host process did not return a proper response.")  PS remote session to each.

All of the following compares show identical configuration:
(1)  Running Windows Services
(2)  accesschk64.exe "Tom" -a *
(3)  WinRM config 
(4)  PS version table

Comment: Enable-PSRemoting

Comment: As stated, powershell remoting generally functions, runs standard PS commands just fine but fails with use of a custom cmdlet. Despite that, I tried re-enabling PS remoting on both the client side and server side ... no change in behavior.
.
At the root of it, wsmprovhost appears to be crashing; I can see that via RemoteDesktop.  I will check the Windows event log.

Comment: Found the problem!  In some situations, the custom-cmdlet may throw an unhandled exception ... this crashes the remote session host (wsmprovhost).  At the client side, it simply sees the session disappear for unknown reason.

The cryptic error (The WSMan provider host process did not return a proper response) means the remote session died for unknown reason.